# Visualise texture based on direction a surface is pointing using Cycles

Tags: shaders, normals

I would like to apply/blend a shader based on the direction a face is pointing. So basically, if the colors of the axes are used, a cube would look like this:

[image]

Ideally, also the negative and positive direction should be taken into account. That way the shader on the face pointing in the `Z+` direction can be different from the one pointing in the `Z-` direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this by plugging the "True Normal" output of the Geometry node into a Diffuse/Emission shader.

Although it is a vector output, it will give you a colour for each face depending upon its normal.

Comment: Thanks. Using an RGB split I can make it work. I'll post the solution as soon as I got it working as expected.

Answer (score 3):

As it turns out you only have to make the normal direction absolute:

[image: Normals to RGB]