# Cycles normal input relative to object's rotation

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, shaders, normals

In continuation to this questions:

[Visualise texture based on direction a surface is pointing using Cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76763/visualise-texture-based-on-direction-a-surface-is-pointing-using-cycles)

Mapping the XYZ colors to faces based on their normal orientation works great. But if I rotate the object, the normal values change. This is even the case when the object is parented to an empty.

Is there a way to lock the normals to the local rotation of the object? Or is this always calculated based on te global values?

Comment: You *could* bake those colors to the texture which is probably unflexible, or try using Texture coordinate node instead. A bit related - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7222/cycles-texture-mapping-generated-coordinates-with-world-orientation

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Adding a vector transform from world to object did the trick.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Mr Zak for the pointer, I started fiddling with the vector transform and that gave me the desired result.

[image]

This is without the vector transform:

[image]

And this is with vector transform:

[image]