# One object with multiple elements ,different colours to elements inside object

Tags: texturing

After applying a particle instance I now have 1 object that has hundred of elements inside 
I would now like to assign random colours to the different elements 
I know how to do it to differnet objects and particle systems but not with one objects that has multiple elements inside 
The object info node , random output is only relevent when the object is duplicated , but the elemnts inside still have the same colour

---

The screenshot shows a sphere with hair particles ( left  )  , for the rendered view I choose path
Then I created a small cube ,  and added a particle instance  modifier , pointed that to the sphere particle system   and applied the modifier 
The result is a sphere (object ) made out of cubes ., right part of the screen.
ONe object with multiple mesh islands

I know how to add differenet materials  to differet faces , and I could do that here too , but we have around thousand cubes here , so doing it manually requires a lot of work 
I basically want 1 material , and apply random colours to the separate mesh islands .
SO far , I have.t found the correct   node module yet .

On the other hand , If I would do it the other way , choose the cube as a rendered object for the particle system , then the particle node , random output  would do wha I want .
But this is not relevant here , since I'm working with an instanced particle object that is applied 
I tried different textures , texture input node set to generated and going into a colour ramp ..all with mixed result , because something one cube has 2 different colours .
So bassically a need a module that goes into a colour ramp , and apply  1 colour to each cube , in a random order 
The particle node random output only works for particle systems and sadly not in my case ( 1 object , multiple mesh islands )

Then we have the object info node , this will work on different objects only , but sadly not mesh islands

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show a Blender screen capture with you settings.  This will make your question clearer.

Comment: Do you mean to say one Mesh has many islands of connected vertices?  Perhaps that lingo in more Blender oriented.

Comment: Any face of a mesh can have a different color.  Please search ... assign different colors to faces of a mesh.

Comment: Please see this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3R0842q6jfE

Comment: I would encourage you to change the word [elements] to [mesh islands] everywhere in your question.  Many software products have a lingo to them.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120290/procedural-random-different-colors-based-on-normal-direction/120294#120294

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Blender Render.

In [Edit] mode  you can place the mouse over a connected vertex group and

press <kbd>l</kbd> the second letter of  B(l)ender to increase your selection .

Then in the materials panel pick one material and click
[assign] button.

---

Particles can be created with different colors in groups or duplicated faces or material nodes so it may be easier to let the creation of particles assign colors for you.

Comment: It comes all down to this , create a cube , go into edit mode and  make duplicates inside it .
now go out of edit mode and assign 1  material to the object , with a node system that controls random colours to the separate mesh cubes inside the object . 
Hope this clear things up