# Shifting/blurring material between objects

Tags: materials, node-editor, blur

I have a feeling this question is either trivial or impossible, but I don't have the blender knowledge to know which.  I have 3 planes all of which share the same material, as shown in the picture below:

[image]

The colour is determined by a the random output from object info put through a wave texture and ColorRamp, so that I can randomly change the colours on the different areas by changing the Wave Texture parameters.
[image]

I would like to produce an element of blur between these objects.  I would prefer real blur, that is an averaging of two neighbouring colours shifted by an amount in space, but if that's impossible I'd settle for a noise/vector curves method, I'm just not sure if that's possible here either.

Thanks, and sorry if this is a really dumb question.

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10453/how-can-you-smooth-the-edge-between-two-materials and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49914/smooth-transition-between-2-materials You can't smooth between materials, you can't smooth between faces, even less so between different objects. Either do it in post-production, or [use a different coloring technique that can be achieved with a single material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120290/procedural-random-different-colors-based-on-normal-direction/120294#120294)

Answer (score 0):

In your ColorRamp node you can set the mode from "constant" to "linear", then add as many control points as you need to get the desired "blurring".

Comment: Thanks Josh but the random number coming from the object is a single number for the entire plane.  When I feed that into the colorramp it will apply a single colour, regardless of how graduated the ramp is.